# php | send dataset via soap

Tags: php, xml, soap, dataset

Hi i need to create a request for sending these data via php soap request. What is the right format to do this?

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <soap:Body>
        <GetVouTrans xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
          <VoucherRequest>
            <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
              <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="kritiria">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="type" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="voucher" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="customer" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:choice>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:schema>
            <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
              <NewDataSet xmlns="">
                <kritiria diffgr:id="kritiria1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                  <type>0</type>
                  <voucher>012345678</voucher>
                  <customer>pexpor213</customer>
                </kritiria>
              </NewDataSet>
            </diffgr:diffgram>
          </VoucherRequest>
        </GetVouTrans>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

How can i send a dataset via soap with php?

i send request but it response me fault. it think i am not sending dataset values in right way :

```
            $faulty = 'Fault method';
            $wsdl = "http://www.speedex.gr/getvoutrans/GetVouTrans.asmx?WSDL";      
            $soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl,
                    array(
                        'trace' => true,
                        'use' => SOAP_LITERAL,
                        'style' => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
                    )
                );  
            $parm = array();
            $parm[] = new SoapVar('0', XSD_SHORT, null, null, 'type' );
            $parm[] = new SoapVar('010658696378', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'voucher' );
            $parm[] = new SoapVar('ΠΕ145031', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'customer' );

            try {
                $resp = $soapClient->GetVouTrans( new SoapVar($parm, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT) );
                print_r ("REQUEST:\n" . htmlentities($soapClient->__getLastRequest()) . "\n");
                print_r ("RESPONSE:\n" . htmlentities($soapClient->__getLastResponse()) . "\n");    
            } catch (SoapFault $e) {
                echo $faulty;
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: What exactly is it that you find difficult?

Comment: @GeirGrusom thanks for response. i think i make something wrong with the way i send dataset

Answer (score 1):

The right way is to use library. Everything is written here http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

**EDIT:**
I dug a bit into this (I'm not sepcialist in SOAP since I don't use it often or like it). However, wsdl file you're using does not specify any of parameters you use. Acually you should be able to use call like:

```
$soapClient->GetVouTrans(0, '010658696378', 'ΠΕ145031' );
// order is important, as WSDL states it. But it doesn't so this call for this web service is not valid.
```

Next, never seen docs and found some here: http://www.speedex.gr/getvoutrans/getvoutrans.asmx?op=GetVouTrans
First strange thing is, that this docs does not state anything about parameters you pass.

Acually, what is strange for me is example request.

```
<soap12:calledMethodName>
// I only seen
<ns1:calledMethodName>
```

I did not find any method, to change it (maybe you need your own SOAP client*).

Next strange thing about this api is: It never returns (no matter of parameters) different response. No error/Exception.

* - Acually, what *might* be the case. Is that they wrote their own implementation of something soap-like. Which is not compatible with standard SOAP libraries.

Have you seen any successfull implementation of someone integrating with their API?

Also, found simmiliar **never answered** question here: [PHP Soap And .Net Dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364189/php-soap-and-net-dataset)

It may turn out, that this API is just not working or requires some specific implementation.

Comment: i use SoapVar but response is false